# Google Sheets API is not working at all?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

I am working on an app right now for my work study position. I am new to iOS programming in general and have never used an API before. I have no idea what I'm doing and it doesn't help that Google's Quickstart isn't working for me either.

I followed the Quickstart completely and now I am at a loss here. I have errors everywhere and no information to fix them. [You can see the code here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) and

[image: here is a screenshot of my code with the numerous errors.]

here is the code I have in Xcode.

```
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GTMOAuth2
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let kKeychainItemName = "Google Sheets API"
    private let kClientID = "<my key>"

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
    // resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
    private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheetsReadonly]

    private let service = GTLRSheetsService()
    let output = UITextView()

    // When the view loads, create necessary subviews
    // and initialize the Google Sheets API service
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        output.frame = view.bounds
        output.editable = false
        output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        output.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]

        view.addSubview(output);

        if let auth = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
            kKeychainItemName,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: nil) {
            service.authorizer = auth
        }

    }

    // When the view appears, ensure that the Google Sheets API service is authorized
    // and perform API calls
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
            canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
            listMajors()
        } else {
            presentViewController(
                createAuthController(),
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }

    // Display (in the UITextView) the names and majors of students in a sample
    // spreadsheet:
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
    func listMajors() {
        output.text = "Getting sheet data..."
        let spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"
        let range = "Class Data!A2:E"
        let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
            .queryWithSpreadsheetId(spreadsheetId, range:range)
        service.executeQuery(query,
                             delegate: self,
                             didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
        )
    }

    // Process the response and display output
    func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                                 finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_ValueRange,
                                 error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        var majorsString = ""
        let rows = result.values!

        if rows.isEmpty {
            output.text = "No data found."
            return
        }

        majorsString += "Name, Major:\n"
        for row in rows {
            let name = row[0]
            let major = row[4]

            majorsString += "\(name), \(major)\n"
        }

        output.text = majorsString
    }



    // Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Sheets API
    private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {
        let scopeString = scopes.joinWithSeparator(" ")
        return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
            scope: scopeString,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: nil,
            keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName,
            delegate: self,
            finishedSelector: "viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:"
        )
    }

    // Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Google Sheets API
    // with the new credentials.
    func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
                        finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?) {

        if let error = error {
            service.authorizer = nil
            showAlert("Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        service.authorizer = authResult
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Helper for showing an alert
    func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
        )
        let ok = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            handler: nil
        )
        alert.addAction(ok)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Am I missing a library or something here?

Comment: Do not post images of code. [Edit] your question and copy and paste relevant code. Clearly explain what issues you are having with your code.

Comment: That's the issue, @rmaddy I don't know what's wrong with my code. At all. I'll paste the code in but I provided a link to where I am getting the code. It's not my code - its google's. I am trying to figure out why it's not working when it obviously was written by an able developer and should work.

Comment: @AshleyMills you are a saint. I have no errors now. Hopefully I can figure things out a little better now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer in case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the code you've copied / written is Swift 2.x, but you're compiling with Swift 3.

In Xcode, **Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax…** may resolve to some extent.